# Place Order Button disabled with Virtual Products, PayPal Express, and Terms and Conditions

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal-express

I have seen some ask this question around the web but without much of an answer given so I'm asking it here.

Customers who are trying to place an order for a **Virtual Product** using **PayPal Express Checkout** are unable to click the Place Order button on the review step after they have clicked the agree checkbox for terms and conditions. The button is disabled after checking the agree checkbox but not before.

This issue does not occur when dealing with a Simple Product or any product that appears to have a shipping method attached. The only visible difference I see on the page is the shipping option selection but I could be missing something.

I would imagine this is some sort of bug and not the intended outcome. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

It may also be important to note that I am using PayPal Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout) method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is with how

> skin/frontend/base/default/js/checkout/review.js

interacts with

> design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express/review.phtml

review.js has not been updated since 1.7 (or maybe before)
review.phtml has been updated with 1.9

When a virtual order happens, there is no shipping section on the review page, and the logic of the "OrderReviewController" tells it to observe all the inputs of the form 'order_review_form', and if they change, to disable the "Place Order" button.

This seems to be a legacy behaviour, because the only remaining input in the 'order_review_form' is the checkbox to agree with Terms and Conditions - and you actually want precisely the opposite behaviour with that checkbox.

The solution:
Create a copy of review.js in your theme's "skin" area, eg:

> skin/frontend/default/modern/js/checkout/review.js

Edit this review.js, and replace line 358

```
Event.observe(input, 'change', this._onElementChange.bindAsEventListener(this));
```

with

```
        if (typeof input.id !== 'string' || input.id.substr(0,9) !== 'agreement') {
            Event.observe(input, 'change', this._onElementChange.bindAsEventListener(this));    
        }
```

A proper solution would require review.js being rewritten to be compatible with review.phtml...

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue in Magento 1.9.1.1 while using the PayPal "all in one" payment solutions; which makes PayPal express checkout a default option when choosing payment method. There is a js conflict that disables my "place order" button when express checkout users return to my site from PayPal site. Because I don't really care about express checkout, I disabled it using the following method:

```
Navigate to System > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods
Select 'Configure' button next to the Payments Pro you have enabled. 
Scroll down to where 'Paypal Express Settings' is detailed.
Select the dropdown 'Payment Applicable From' and change to a country that you do not take payments from (i.e. Some Country you're not selling in) and save configuration
You will then no longer see the Express Checkout option when user is choosing payment options.
```

So if express checkout is not a requirement for PayPal "All in one" users, disable it all together using this method. You will also need to select "no" under "Display on Product Details Page" and "Display on Shopping Cart" which is under "Basic Setting PayPal Express Checkout".

Hope this helps! At least temporarily until you get your Magento theme's js conflicts resolved.