# Payment process failed because checkboxes/button does not work correct (PayPal)! - Version 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, onepage-checkout, payment

### The problem

... is, that customers could not complete the order, because after the PayPal login they return back to the order overview and can't click on the "Jetzt bezahlen (Pay now)" button. The button is disabled, even if the checkbox of AGB (T&C) etc. are checked.

Curiously, the button is active and clickable before clicking a checkbox. After clicking one checkbox the button is disabled and it stays disabled. Its only at the payment method PayPal on Magento Community Ver. 1.9.2.4.

### The question:

Is there any fix for this problem yet? German Magento shops still have problems with greyed 'Jetzt kaufen' buttons, T&C checkboxes and PayPal.

*BTW.: PayPal seems to work fine! If you deactivate the requirement of the checkboxes, the order can be placed, as usual!*

What about the newer version Magento +2.0? Does it the trick?

Here is an screenshot (German order process, after redirect from PayPal):

[image: Screenshot of checkout process (after PayPal redirect to checkout overview:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **The solution:**

After debugging the problem for two days, I finally came accross this solution:

1. Search the file "**.../app/design/frontend/default//[THEME]/template/paypal/express/review.phtml**" (If you don't have this file in your theme, just copy it from the base theme)
2. Add the following lines of code after "*//Workaround to unbind the event listeners for the agreement checkboxes*" at the bottom of the file.

Add this (Take the code from here: https://gist.github.com/4503260):

```
//Workaround to unbind the event listeners for the agreement checkboxes
  var agreementsBlock = $$('.checkout-agreements p.agree')[0];
  if(agreementsBlock != undefined) {
     agreementsBlock.replace('<p class="agree">' + agreementsBlock.innerHTML + '</p>');
}
//]]>
</script>
```

bellow line 175:

```
PayPalExpressAjax = new OrderReviewController($('order_review_form'), $('review_button'),
        $('shipping_method'), $('shipping_method_form'), 'details-reload'
    );
    PayPalExpressAjax.addPleaseWait($('review-please-wait'));
```

3. This solution won't work for two checkboxes. So if you have two agreements to check (e.g. AGBs & Widerrufsbelehrungen), show them together in one box or provide two links to open them individually.

> Credits to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14262466/5594625 *by ceckoslab*

---

**( ! ) This could maybe helpful for you too:**
[Place Order Button disabled with Virtual Products, PayPal Express, and Terms and Conditions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62398/place-order-button-disabled-with-virtual-products-paypal-express-and-terms-and)

Thanks for your help and messages! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this solution is helpful for multiple checkboxes. In my case it was ...

```
// Workaround to unbind the event listeners for the agreement checkboxes - v2
var agreementsBlocks = $$('.checkout-agreements p.agree');
if (agreementsBlocks.length) {
   agreementsBlocks.each(function(agreementsBlock) {
      agreementsBlock.replace('<p class="agree">' + agreementsBlock.innerHTML + '</p>');
  });
}
```