# Paypal - accept Terms & Conditions not working

Tags: paypal, magento-1.9.3.3, terms-and-conditions

This is a problem reported several times with many possible solutions.

Customer is redirected from Paypal back to website 
`https://www.example_website.com/paypal/express/review/` page. He has to check that he agrees with terms & conditions. But after checking that and clicking "Place Order" button, he's redirected back to the same page with message "You need to accept Terms & Conditions in order to proceed" or "Order payment Failed. Please try again later..."

I have tried

- changing `skin/frontend/base/default/js/checkout/review.js` file ([Place Order Button disabled with Virtual Products, PayPal Express, and Terms and Conditions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62398/place-order-button-disabled-with-virtual-products-paypal-express-and-terms-and))
- changing `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express/review.phtml` file (https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Technical-Issues/Payment-process-failed-because-checkboxes-button-does-not-work/m-p/33826#M3194)
- installing this extension (https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep)
- installing this extension (https://github.com/thinklikeamage/Stabilis_PaypalExpressRedirect)

and other numerous solutions I cannot recall, but nothing really worked.

Does anybody know the source of this issue? **It started as soon as I enabled Terms and Agreements in checkout. Before that, all payments through Paypal were completed normally.**

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment I have to do it through this way, but maybe you should take a look at this topic. Maybe it holds some information to get you back on track: [Validation of the terms and conditions (custom module)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222416/validation-of-the-terms-and-conditions-custom-module)

Check the HTTP requests and their content. Is the value of the key called `agreements_id` empty?